# Using Spring JPA Specification with OData Queries

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, odata

so i have a spring boot application and my data source is MySQL via JPA. I am trying to introduce Odata queries to my API's and then fetch data based on those odata params. I was wondering if there are any utils or external libraries i can use to parse the odata query then construct the JPA Specification. I have looked into olingo but im not sure if it is exactly what i am looking for. I was thinking of parsing the query text, and constructing the jpa specifications manually(maybe use reflection is necessary), but if anyone has any tips or advice on how to better approach this it would be much appreciated!!

I was thinking of doing something similar to this but with odata instead. Only issue i see is making this dynamic enough to handle every complex odata query coming in.
https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications

Comment: That same site gives a spring boot odata example [using olingo](https://www.baeldung.com/olingo)

Comment: You might consider https://github.com/mhewedy/spring-data-jpa-mongodb-expressions as an alternative for OData to query jpa repositories using the intuitive MongoDB query language